# Kotlin in Flutter application causing Crash

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart

Since the last flutter update there has been an issue when I try to use the media player plugin witch uses Kotlin.

When you hit the button and it is suppose to play the audio file, it causes the application to crash.

```
fun play(url: String) {
    player.reset()
    channel.invokeMethod("onPosition", 0.0)
    player.setDataSource(url)
    player.prepareAsync()
    channel.invokeMethod("onIsLoading", null)
    task?.cancel()
    task = object : TimerTask() {
      override fun run() {
        if (player.isPlaying) {
          session.setPlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
              .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, player.currentPosition.toLong(), 1f)
              .build())
            channel.invokeMethod("onPosition", player.currentPosition.toDouble() / player.duration.toDouble())
        }
      }
    }
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 100)
  }
```

it was suggested that I add this in.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable {
  channel.invokeMethod(...)
})
```

but I if I do I get

```
Unresolved Reference: activity
```

This is the error message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Methods marked with @UiThread must be executed on the main thread. Current thread: Timer-0
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread(FlutterJNI.java:605)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.dispatchPlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:515)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.send(DartMessenger.java:76)
        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartExecutor.send(DartExecutor.java:166)
        at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.send(FlutterNativeView.java:155)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:98)
        at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(MethodChannel.java:84)
        at live.exit.musicplayer.MusicPlayer$play$1.run(MusicPlayer.kt:49)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:562)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:512)
```

I am at a bit of a loss, this is suppose to be playing audio.

I know NOTHING about kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using ragotrebor music-player plugin (https://gitlab.com/ragotrebor). Looking at their history a merge was made about a month ago which should fix this issue.

Just update to the latest version of the plugin and you should be good to go!

**Background**

It's related to a change in flutter to fix a bug which caused FlutterJNI (Java Native Interface) to crash intermittently when certain methods were executed outside of the main thread. Flutter was changed to thrown an exception in all cases, to avoid this intermittent crash and force developers to run methods correctly on the UI thread. Unfortunately this caused many existing plugins to crash and developers were required to update their source code.

**Reference links**

- Change with discussion: https://github.com/flutter/engine/commit/2c9e37c34e79475bbde7c8163eb5e56cdb9662a
- Found through this thread discussing a fix for a specific plugin: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34993).
- Merge request details for music player plugin that fixed this issue: https://gitlab.com/exitlive/music-player/commit/693131a7f0d29b3ee42ba9fa2a5ce65aef7652fb

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: @slfan thanks for the feedback, I updated the answer accordingly. Hopefully that's what you meant.